# Materialistic design in android ice cream sandwich

Tags: android

I need to develop an app with materialistic design. I have set `API 15` (ice cream sandwich)  as min `SDK` can I use materialistic design in it or should I set min sdk higher.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **AppCompat library** to achieve this or use some third party libraries.
[MaterialDesignLibrary](https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary)

Answer (score 0):

Use android support library **android-support-v7-appcompat** to see the effect of material design in lower API.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Recycler View , Card View etc. using AppCompat library but ripple effect is not provided by the AppCompat library so you have to use custom libraries below Lolipop for ripple effect.

Links for third party libraries:

[Material Design Library](https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary)

Comment: https://github.com/traex/RippleEffect here you can find custom ripple effect and it support min api-9